# VBA ADO Excel-2010 How to assign a ADO connection to a pivot table data source

Tags: excel, vba, ado

How do I or can I assign an ADO connection to a pivot tables data source in excel 2010? I want to do this as a workaround for excel not being able to have password protected files connected without them being open.

I will include two code snippets below.

Code to iterate over all pivot tables to change data source to an existing connection

```
Sub changeConnection()
  Dim pTable As Variant
  Dim sheet As Variant
  Dim workBookName As String 

  workBookName = "filename.xlsm"      

  For Each sheet In Workbooks(workBookName).Worksheets
    For Each pTable In sheet.PivotTables
     pTable.changeConnection Workbooks(workBookName ).Connections("connection name")
    Next pTable
   Next sheet

End Sub
```

Code to create an ADO connection on a password protected file.

```
 Public Function readFile()
  Dim xl As Object
  Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
  Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim conString As String
  Dim wkbName As String
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim DBPath As String

 'Path to excel file
 DBPath = "path\to\file.xlsm"
 Set xl = GetObject(DBPath)

'Name of table
wkbName = "[IS$]"

conString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

'Query
SQL = "select * from " & wkbName

'Open connection
conn.Open conString

 'Itterate over record set
 Set recSet = New ADODB.Recordset
 recSet.Open SQL, conn

 'Print out col1 from table
  Do Until recSet.EOF
  'process your data here
  Debug.Print recSet!ISData
  recSet.MoveNext
  Loop
End Function
```

Any suggestions would be awesome on how I could try this. I don't want to use open workbook as this is meant to be used by several people.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Duplicate of [VBA ADO Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664756/vba-ado-excel-2010). If you have additional information to share about your issue, please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51664756/edit).

Comment: Fine....................